# Durandal js 1.2.0 with Hottowel SPA doesnt scroll on iPhone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, durandal, hottowel

I have started a new MVC4 HotTowel SPA test project with a list (ul element) in the Details page. 
This worked ok when viewing with an iPhone - it scrolled ok. Then I used nuget to update the 3 durandal packages in the template (from 1.1.1 to 1.2.0). After that the details page will not scroll on the iphone.

Is this a bug in the durandal updated code or is it by design (in which case how should i implement scrolling) ?

Also, just checked the Durandal Starter kit project - this doesnt scroll on the iPhone either

Answer (score 2):

open up durandal/app.js and comment out the below:

```
adaptToDevice: function() {
    //document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //};
}
```

hope this helps - this one was a bugger.